# Flower identification: Moscow, Russia

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this plant near the MSU, Moscow, Russia. Could someone help me to identify it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look into species in the [Caprifoliaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprifoliaceae) family, for instance species in the [*Knautia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knautia_arvensis) genus. The flowers and leafs in your pics look very similar to these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks very similar to [Cephalaria gigantea](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cephalaria_gigantea).

[image]